# Under which conditions is it possible to find points with same distances under bi-Lipschitz map

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry

Given two metric spaces $(X,d_X), (Y, d_Y)$, a bi-Lipschitz map $f:X \to Y$ and a finite set of points $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\} \in X$. Consider in addition, that $X$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, concretely some $l^p$ space. Under which conditions is it possible to find points $\{y_1, \ldots, y_n\} \in Y$ such that for each pair of points $x_i,x_j$ we have $d_X(x_i, x_j) = d_Y(y_i, y_j)$?

Comment: Rephrased: *let $X,Y$ be bilipschitz homeomorphic metric spaces. Under what condition is it true that $X$ and $Y$ are "finitely isometric"?* (where "finitely isometric" means that every finite subset of $X$ is isometric to some finite subset of $Y$?). The question sounds a bit vague, what do you except other than trivial restatements or a list of spaces that are both bilipschitz and finitely isometric?

Comment: @YCor I would guess that some connectedness assumptions might help, so that continuity arguments become possible. The intention of the question could be that the points $y_i$ are not too far away from $f(x_i)$ - maybe the OP wants to clarify this? I agree that the question is a bit too vague, but is it really so bad that it has to be closed?

Comment: Let me specialise it a bit. Concretely I am wondering if given a bi-Lip. map from an $l^p$ (sequence) space X to any other space Y, if then the above statement always holds.

Comment: If you change the question, you should edit it with the changes.

Comment: Well, if you only assume that $X$ is an $\ell^p$-space and $Y$ is any metric space, you have an endless list of trivial counterexamples... and even when $Y$ is also a Banach space.

Comment: @YCor I disagree with your statement. For example the Banach-space-theoretical version of the question asked by CAT0 which I suggest in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/227073 is of interest. Possibly other, more metric-geometrical versions are also of interest. I would suggest to re-open this question.

Comment: @MikhailOstrovskii Your new question is a reasonable one since it's specific (unlike something vague such as "under which conditions...").

Comment: @YCor I do not see an obvious answer to the question of CAT0 either, if we restate it as: Let $Y$ be a metric space bilipschitz-equivalent to $\ell_p$, $1<p<\infty$. Is it true that any finite subset of $\ell_p$ is isometric to a subset of $Y$? (There are much stronger chances to construct a counterexample than in my question, but I do not see an  obvious counterexample in this case, too.)

Comment: See Weaver's answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/227196/ for a counterexample to the question in the previous comment.

Answer (score 4):

This can go very wrong in totally disconnected spaces.

For instance, if $X$ and $Y$ are both finite, one can adjust the distances between points via the bi-Lipschitz map so that every collection of points gets their distances changed.

Even further, you can let $X$ be the rationals and let $Y$ be constructed by recursively moving each point of $X$ to a point in a distinct coset of the rationals, moving each point by only $1/2^n$, say. This is another example of a pair of spaces where you can never map a collection of points isometricly.